# Want program to continue even when there is an exception

Tags: c++, exception

I have searched a few times but I kinda, didnt found what i exactly wanted.

I was working out with exceptional handling (try/catch), where i found this obstacle. If the program finds an exception, it terminated whatsoever.

I tried calling a function in the `catch` part, but it still terminates.

```
void exception_handle() //This is for handling exception if user inputs a char instead of int//
{
user_play uplay;
try
 {
    uplay.usersentry();
 }
catch(std::runtime_error& e)
 {
    cout<<"Input a string bro, not a character"<<endl;
    user_input();
 }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
class user_play //this class is for letting user play the game by allowing them to enter desired number in the desired empty space//
{
 public:
 void usersentry()
  {
    int tempdata;
    retry:
     cout<<"\n\n Enter the row and coloumn where you want to enter data"<<endl;
     cin>>i>>j;
        if (i>=1 && i<=9 && j>=1 && j<=9)
        {
            cout<<"\n Enter your desired value to put in that place"<<endl;
            cin>>tempdata;
            if(tempdata>=1 && tempdata<=9)
            {
                data=tempdata;
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Soduku contains numbers from 1 to 9 only.Please try again");
                loops++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Soduku row exists between 1 and 9 only.Please try again");
            loops++;    
        }
   }
};
```

Here is the function(It's incomplete as i am trying to debugg)

```
int user_input() //this one is for taking correct value from user and storing it in its respective place//
{
a=0;
//Object Declaration//
rowrules rr;
columnrules cr;

//for handling the program exceptions
exception_handle();

//rules for row and column
//rr.rrules();
//cr.crules();
//ruleselect();
//i--;
//j--;
if(a==0)
{
    soduku[i-1][j-1]=data;
  return soduku[i-1][j-1];
}
else
 {
    user_input();
 }
}
```

here as you see i tried calling the function in `catch` part but still the program terminated.Am I missing something basic?? Or is there any other solution/method/logic?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `catch(...)`?  You're going to have to provide a [mcve] if you want help figuring out why it is not working.

Comment: Yes I did `catch`, it works but i am looking for is a way to continue the prog even if reaches to `catch`.

Comment: You should really include the part of the code that's not working with your question.

Comment: That is not possible in `C++`, and also not recommended. Wrap with a loop the code for which you want to repeat if the exception happens.

Comment: done, i've added the part of program....not possible.? @Dialecticus plz explain more

Comment: @PrasinShrestha: The example is still not a [mcve]. However, likely your `usersentry` function is not throwing a `std::runtime_error` but something else. What happens if you replace `std::runtime_error& e` with `(...)`?

Comment: Where in the code you provided do you do `catch (...)`?

Comment: if failure is expected, *Don't Use Exceptions*. Exceptions are intended for _Exceptional_ occurrences and should be avoided for normal control flow.

Comment: It sounds like your program throws another exception in `user_input` when still dealing with the first one caught, which results in a call of `std::terminate`.

Comment: On hold...?? I have edited the question..aww come on guys.a user is asking help/recommendations here

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to continue execution from the place where C++ exception is thrown. C++ exceptions are not designed for that. But it is possible to repeat the code you want repeated if the exception happens:

```
for (bool success = false; !success; )
{
    try
    {
        <some code that should be repeated if exception happens>

        success = true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}
```

Note that in general case it is a bad idea to do absolutely nothing if exception happens. At least write something down in some log file, if you have it.

Comment: or better yet, don't use exceptions if failure is expected

Comment: @Mgetz Maybe not an option in OP's case. Maybe "uplay" code is a third party library.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't want to encourage this sort of pattern if we can avoid it. In general Exceptions are for the thing that can fail but is not expected to. In this case they are expecting failure, so they should use an alternative mechanism.

Comment: @PrasinShrestha validation is always an expected error, you're checking for it. An unexpected error would be something like stdin closing.

Comment: @Mgetz Okay...but uhh i m just asking there is a way to continue a prog if exception is found, if yes then how.

Comment: @PrasinShrestha I'm suggesting you're approaching the problem wrong in the first place, an exception may not be appropriate here. Consider `std::optional` instead.

Comment: @Mgetz okay i will try it and see for results(btw i m beginner so be easy on me, M'kay? )